# How to get image on other table while editing on other page

Tags: php, database, laravel

1) I am trying to get one image when user edit a petition, i Have two tables Petition and users
it's users image i want to save in users table's profile_img_url attribute

this is my post_edit method in AdminPetitonController's file.

**2) How can use eager loading here, i mean just by using
      $SponceringUser instead of $ProfileUser. so i don't need to run two
      separate queries.**

```
 public function post_edit($id = null)
{
    if ($id)
    {
        $Petition = Petition::find($id);

        if (!$Petition)
        {
            //oh noes! invalid petition specified!
            Alert::error("That petition no longer exists");
            return Redirect::action('AdminPetitionsController@index');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Petition = new Petition;
    }

    $PetitionCreationForm = new AdminPetitionCreationForm;
    $errors = array();

    if ($PetitionCreationForm->passes())
    {
        $Petition->call_to_action = Input::get('call_to_action');

        if (empty($Petition->id))
        {
            $Petition->slug = Str::slug($Petition->call_to_action);
        }

        $Petition->recipient = Input::get('recipient');


        if (Input::get('feature_type') == '1')
        {
            $Petition->featured_sort_order = Input::get('featured_sort_order') + 1;
            $Petition->flag_featured = 1;
        }
        else if(Input::get('feature_type') == '0')
        {
            $Petition->featured_sort_order=null;
            $Petition->flag_featured = 0;
        }
        //$selected_position = Input::get('dropdown_menu_list');
        $Petition->description_md = Input::get('description_md');
        $Petition->description = Petition::parseMD($Petition->description_md);

        $Petition->letter_md = Input::get('letter_md');
        $Petition->letter = Petition::parseMD($Petition->letter_md);

        $Petition->target_signatures = Input::get('target_signatures', 50000);
        $Petition->flag_published = Input::get('flag_published');

        $Petition->media_type = Input::get('media_type', null);

        if (Input::get('media_type') == 'img' && Input::hasFile('petition_image'))
        {
            $Petition->media_url = Petition::uploadFile(Input::file('petition_image'));
        }
        else if (Input::get('media_type') == 'youtube' && Input::get('media_url_youtube'))
        {
            $Petition->media_url = Input::get('media_url_youtube');
        }


        //  how to fix this part .... gurrrrrrrrrrrr=======================
        $ProfileUser= $Petition->User();

        if (Input::get('profile_type') == 'image' && Input::hasFile('profile_image'))
        {
            $ProfileUser->profile_img_url =  Petition::uploadFile(Input::file('profile_image'));
        }
        else if (Input::get('profile_type') == 'url' && Input::get('profile_url'))
        {
            $ProfileUser->profile_img_url = Input::get('profile_url');
        }
        //$Petition->sponsor_user_id = $SponsoringUser->id;
        $ProfileUser->save();
        //====================================================

        try {
            try {
                $SponsoringUser = User::where('email', Input::get('user.email'))->firstOrFail();
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                $PetitionSponsorForm = new AdminPetitionSponsorForm(Input::get('user'));

                if ($PetitionSponsorForm->passes())
                {
                    $SponsoringUser = new User;
                    $SponsoringUser->email = Input::get('user.email');
                    $SponsoringUser->first_name = Input::get('user.first_name');
                    $SponsoringUser->last_name = Input::get('user.last_name');
                    $SponsoringUser->populateLocation(Input::get('user.zip'));

                    $SponsoringUser->save();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
            $Petition->save();
```

how to fix that part specifically(i highlighted) i guess i just messed that part. 
it gives me errr that save is undefined method for it i am not sure do i need to make anoher variable like $ProfileUser or not.

for more details here is gist:  https://gist.github.com/gupta2205/b33dcf762876e5df34d9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your Gist but do you have the User relationship set up in your Petition model?

If so, try changing the line in question to this:

```
$ProfileUser= $Petition->User;
```

Comment: oh really , i am messing up everything because of that lil brackets :O
 thanks :) it worked

Comment: Glad it helped. Here's the section in the Laravel docs that explains why it works like this: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties

Comment: thanks ! can i ask one more thing ? here iam running two saprate queries. how can i use only $SponceringUser instead of $ProfileUser. how can i use eager loading here.

Comment: Maggi, you should make a new question to get the best answers. It's a different problem to the first one.

Comment: sure ! here it is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853907/how-can-use-eager-loading-here-i-mean-just-by-using-one-variable-instead-of-two